Genus of function fields, Riemann-Roch and base field extension
Let $K$ be a one variable function field over any base field $k_0$. By that,  I mean a field extension of transcendantal degree 1. Let $k$ denote the constant field of $K$. By that I mean the field made of element $x\in K$ such that $|x|_v\leq 1$ for any place $v$ of $K$ trivial on $k_0$. I am precisely interested in the case where $k_0$ is NOT $k$. Let $X$ be the unique normal projective curve (in the sense of [Liu, Def 2.5.29]) whose function field is $K$.
My question concerns the definitions of the genus of $K$ and $X$ and the Riemann-Roch theorems.
Short version: Why does the definition of the genus of K always involves $k$ where the definition of the genus of X only involves $k_0$?
In more details: Here is the definition of the genus of $K$ from Chapter XIV Artin Algebraic numbers and algebraic functions. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be any divisor (formal sum of places of K). We have
$$\begin{align*} \text{deg}(\mathfrak{a})&:=\sum_{v}\mathfrak{a}_v * f(v|v_{|k}) \\ 
\Pi_\mathfrak{a}&:= \{x\in \mathbb{A}_K ~|~\text{ord}_v(x_v)\geq \mathfrak{a}_v\}, \\
l(\mathfrak{a})&:=\text{dim}_{k}~\Pi_\mathfrak{a}\cap K,  \\
r(\mathfrak{a})&:=\text{dim}_k ~(\mathbb{A}_K/\Pi_\mathfrak{a}+K).
\end{align*}$$
and the genus is defined as $g(K):=1+r(\mathfrak{a})-l(\mathfrak{a})-\text{deg}(\mathfrak{a})$.
Now, the arithmetic genus of $X$ is defined in Definition 7.3.19 of Liu's book as
$$g_a(X):=1-\chi_{k_0}(O_X):=1-\dim_{k_0}~H^0(X,O_X)+\text{dim}_{k_0}~H^1(X,O_X). $$
And Riemann-Roch theorem says that for any divisor $D$, $\chi_{k_0}(O_X(D))=\text{deg}(D)+1-g_a(X)$ where this times the degree of $D$ is computed over $k_0$.
My questions :
-Do we have $g_a(X)=g(K)$ ? That seems weird because $g_a(X)$ depends on $k_0$ where $g(K)$ only depends on $k$.
-What is the connection between $O_X(X)$ and $k$ ?
-If $Y$ is the unique normal porjective curve over $k$ whose function field is $K$, what is the connection between $X$ and $Y$ ?
-What is the connection between $H^1(X,O_X)$ and $\mathbb{A}_K/\Pi_\mathfrak{a}+K$ ?
